# Assigning a value from one table to other table

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-update, dml

There are two tables Table A and Table B. These contains the same columns cost and item. The Table B contains the list of items and their corresponding costs whereas the Table A contains only the list of items.

Now we need to check the items of Table A, if they are present in the Table B then the corresponging item cost should be assigned to the item's cost in Table A.

**Can someone help me out by writing a query for this.**

Consider the tables as shown:

Table A:

```
item    cost
------------- 
pen     null
book    null
watch   null
```

Table B:

```
item     cost
------------- 
watch    1000
book     50
```

Expected output

```
Table A:

item    cost
pen       0
book     50
watch   1000
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add a foreign key (primary key of table A) in the Table B as you can say table A `ID` then add a join(right join may be) in the query to get or assign the prices respective items.

`join` be like

```
SELECT item, cost
    FROM tablename a
    RIGHT JOIN tablename b ON a.item= b.item;
```

**Edit:**

Just edit this table name ,now run it.

Comment: According to your query, we cannot assign the item name to the cost. It throws an error and by the way select is to display but I need the cost value to be assigned to the items in Table A from Table B.

Answer (score 0):

There are plenty of ways you could do this, if you are taking table b to be the one containing the price then a left outer join would do the trick.

```
SELECT
    table_a.item,
    CASE
        WHEN table_b.cost IS NULL
        THEN 0
        ELSE table_b.cost
    END as cost
FROM table_a
LEFT OUTER JOIN table_b ON table_a.item = table_b.item
```

The result also appears to suggest that pen which is not in table b should have a price of 0 (this is bad practice) but for the sake of returning the desired result you will want a case statement to assign a value if it is null.

In order to update the table, as per the comment

```
update table_a set cost = some_alias.cost
from (
    SELECT
        table_a.item,
        CASE
        WHEN table_b.cost IS NULL
        THEN 0
        ELSE table_b.cost
        END as cost
    FROM table_a
    LEFT OUTER JOIN table_b ON table_a.item = table_b.item
) some_alias
where table_a.item = some_alias.item
```

Comment: Thanks! This works correct. but I want the values to be assigned to the items in table A. which doesnt happen with your query.

Comment: update table_a from -> sql query -> where item = query.item you should be able to take it from there

Comment: This isn't working correct. All the values of cost in the table_a are assigning as 0.

Comment: This does smell a lot like homework but for the sake of completeness ```update table_a set cost = some_alias.cost
from (
 SELECT
     table_a.item,
     CASE
  WHEN table_b.cost IS NULL
  THEN 0
  ELSE table_b.cost
     END as cost
 FROM table_a
 LEFT OUTER JOIN table_b ON table_a.item = table_b.item
) some_alias
where table_a.item = some_alias.item```

Answer (score 0):

I would structure the update like this:

```
with cost_data as (
  select
    item,
    max (cost) filter (where item = 'watch') as watch,
    max (cost) filter (where item = 'book') as book
  from table_b
  group by item
)
update table_a a
set
  watch = c.watch,
  book = c.book
from cost_data c
where
  a.item = c.item and
 (a.watch is distinct from c.watch or
  a.book is distinct from c.book)
```

In essence, I am doing a common table expression to do a poor man's pivot table on the Table B to get the rows into columns.  One caveat here -- if there are multiple costs listed for the same item, this may not do what you want, but then you would need to know how to handle that in almost any case.

Then I am doing an "update A from B" against the CTE.

The last part is not critical, per se, but it is helpful -- to limit the query to only execute on rows that need to change.  It's best to limit DML if it doesn't need to occur (the best way to optimize something is to not do it).